# How can I use "&" in my SQL query without it breaking?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my SQL query which works great unless there is '&' in `value2`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM isproducts WHERE title = 'LBD - ".$value2."' AND ProductGroupCode = 'WEB' LIMIT 1";
```

Is this a known issue which I don't know about?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: What is the error? If it's a MySQL syntax error remember to paste the part where it says "near ..." and your full SQL statement.

Comment: It just doesnt continue the code, and no i havn't escaped value 2.  How would i go about doing that?

Comment: @Andy: `mysql_real_escape_string($value2)`

Comment: If it doesn't continue the code then it must have quietly died with a fatal error. See if you can turn error reporting on in php.ini.

Comment: Does that go before the query?

Comment: @Andy: Please do as BoltClock said: Post the exact error message with the actual query that caused it.

Comment: @Andy: Yeah, or when you concatenate it into the query as shown in Pradeep Singh's answer.

Comment: as a matter of fact, mysql_real_escape_string has nothing to do with & symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM isproducts WHERE title = 'LBD - ".mysql_real_escape_string($value2)."' AND ProductGroupCode = 'WEB' LIMIT 1";
```